# Is the sum of 2 Lebesgue measurable sets measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the sum of two measurable set measurable? I think it is not...

Comment: See also the previous MO question concerning sums of Borel sets http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48571/borel-set-plus-a-closed-set-borel/48579#48579

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Evidently, there are [measure zero sets with a non measurable sum](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/prepF/89A+A/89A+A.pdf). The article begins as follows:

> > Krzysztof Ciesielski, 
> >     Hajrudin Fejzi´c, Chris Freiling,
> >
> > **Measure zero sets with non-measurable sum**
> >
> > > > Abstract
> > > >
> > > > For any C ⊆ R there is a subset A ⊆ C such that A + A has inner
> > > >         measure zero and outer measure the same as C + C. Also, there is a
> > > >         subset A of the Cantor middle third set such that A+A is Bernstein in
> > > >         [0, 2]. On the other hand there is a perfect set C such that C + C is an
> > > >         interval I and there is no subset A ⊆ C with A + A Bernstein in I.
> >
> > 1 Introduction.
> >
> > It is not at all surprising that there should be measure zero sets, A, whose sum
> >     A+A = {x+y : x ∈ A, y ∈ A} is non-measurable. Ask a typical mathematician
> >     why this should be so and you are likely to get the following response:
> >
> > > > The Cantor middle-third set, when added to itself gives an entire
> > > >         interval, [0, 2]. So certainly there exists a measure zero set that
> > > >         when added to itself gives a non-measurable set.
> >
> > The intuition being that an interval has much more content than is needed for
> >     a non-measurable set.
> >     Indeed such sets do exist (in ZFC). Sierpi´nski (1920) seems to be the first
> >     to address this issue. Actually, he shows the existence of measure zero sets
> >     X, Y such that X+Y is non-measurable (see [7]). The paper by Rubel (see [6])
> >     in 1963 contains the first proof that we could find for the case X = Y (see also
> >     [5]). Ciesielski [3] extends these results to much greater generality, showing
> >     that A can be a measure zero Hamel basis, or it can be a (non-measurable)
> >     Bernstein set and that A+A can also be Bernstein. He also establishes similar
> >     results for multiple sums, A + A + A etc.
> >
> > This paper is mainly about the statement above and the intuition behind
> >     it. Below we list four conjectures, each of which seems justified by extending
> >     this line of reasoning.
> >
> > 1. Not only does such a set exist, but it can be taken to be a subset of the
> >        Cantor middle-third set, C. (This does not seem to immediately follow
> >        from any of the above proofs. Thomson [9, p. 136] claims this to be
> >        true, but without proof.)
> > 2. The intuition really has nothing to do with the precise structure of the
> >        Cantor set, which might lead one to conjecture the following. Suppose
> >        C is any set with the property that C + C contains a set of positive
> >        measure. Then there must exist a subset A ⊆ C such that A + A is
> >        non-measurable.
> > 3. The intuition relies on the fact that non-measurable sets can have far
> >        less content than an entire interval. Therefore, the claim should also
> >        hold when non-measurable is replaced by other similar qualities. Recall
> >        that if I is a set then a set S is called Bernstein in I if and only if
> >        both S and its complement intersect every non-empty perfect subset
> >        of I. Constructing a set that is Bernstein in an interval is one of the
> >        standard ways of establishing non-measurability. Certainly, any set that
> >        is Bernstein in an interval has far less content than the interval itself.
> >        Therefore, we might conjecture that there is a subset A ⊆ C
> >        with A+A
> >        Bernstein in [0,2].
> > 4. Combining the reasoning behind the Conjectures 2 and 3, let C be any
> >        set with the property that C + C contains an interval, I. We might
> >        conjecture that there must exist a subset A ⊆ C such that A + A is
> >        Bernstein in I.
> >
> > We will settle these four conjectures in the next four sections.

The paper goes on to show that conjectures 1, 2 and 3 are true, but 4 is false.

Comment: "The Cantor middle-third set, when added to itself gives an entire interval, [0, 2]. So certainly there exists a measure zero set that when added to itself gives a non-measurable set." -- If I am not mistaken, is this claiming that the closed interval [o,2] is not Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @Regenbogen: I think the measure zero set is going to be a proper subset of the Cantor middle-third set :-) 

Comment: Regenbogen, I believe that the idea is to pass to subsets to get the counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the paper! But I'd like to see a proof here... But if no proofs come or if they are too difficult to be written here, or if there is not a relative simple counter-example, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Nicolo Martini. In wikipedia it is stated that to show the existence of non-Lebesgue-measurable sets you have to go beyond ZF axioms of set theory. So I suspect "easy" proofs of what you want will be hard to come by.

Comment: To construct a non-measurable Lebesgue set you only need axiom of choice...

Comment: @Nicolo Martini: Oh! I knew the example that any Hamel basis is a non-Borel-measurable set. Are there such easy examples of non-Lebesgue-measurable sets?

Comment: Yes, the Vitali set, you can find the construction on Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for the example and apologies for bothering with elementary questions.

Comment: @NM: You should accept this answer.  JDH has given a reference that exactly answers your question, and even a link to the paper.

Comment: What about Borel sets?

Comment: John Jiang, excellent question! Why not ask it as an MO question? Is the sum of two Borel sets necessarily measurable?

Comment: @John Jiang: Joel is right, this should be a MO question since the answer is a little different and equally interesting.

Comment: But do you want to ask if the sum of two Borel sets is Borel?  The sum is Lebesgue measurable, as already noted.

Comment: Here is a construction of two Borel sets whose sum is not Borel:  P. Erdõs, A. H. Stone:  On the sum of two Borel sets,  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.  25 (1970), 304--306 available here: http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1970-15.pdf

Comment: Great paper! +1

Answer (score 6):

Note that the problem is trivial if you talk about subsets of the plane $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.  Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ be non-measurable, then $A\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$ both have Lebesgue measure 0 in the plane, but their sum $A\times \mathbb R$ is not measurable.

Comment: I stole this argument from gowers [Borel plus Borel = Borel?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48571/borel-set-plus-a-closed-set-borel/48577#48577). (Who probably stole it from Sierpinski, or Euclid.) 


Comment: why is $A\times \mathbb R$ non measurable?

Comment: Replace $\mathbb R$ by $I:=[0,1]$. Let $B:=I\setminus A$. If $A\times I$ and $B\times I$ are measurable with measure $a$ and $b:=1-a$ respectively, then find closed sets $C_n\subseteq A\times I$ with measure $\ge a-1/n$, similarly $D_n\subseteq B\times I$. Their (analytic, hence measurable) projections $C'_n\subseteq A$, $D'_n\subseteq B$ are disjoint and have a combined 1-dimensional measure $\ge 1-2/n$. Hence $A=\bigcup_n C'_n$ up to a measure zero set.  (There must be a simpler argument...)

Answer (score 5):

I think the sum of 2 Borel sets is analytic, hence measurable.